# sum(births) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi everyone, 
             I am using a sample data in RStudio. I used the code below:

```
 njnew <- nj %>%
     group_by(NAME_2) %>%
   summarise(Num.totalbirths=sum(births),
             Num.totalvulnerable=sum(vulnerable)) %>%
    mutate(percent.potentailcase=potentialcase/Num.totalpotentialcase,
           percent.vulerablecase=vulnerable/Num.vulnerablecase)
```

I get after running:

```
Error in sum(births) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

My dataset is an csv but I manually added/filled in 2 additional columns (births, vulnerable).

Could you kindly let me know how this error may have happened?

Comment: please provide an example of your data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message, it looks like `births` is of type `character`. However, you can only compute the `sum` of numeric, complex or logical vectors. This likely happened when you manually added the column after reading in the csv.

You can double-check the type of the variable with `class(nj$births)`, which probably returns `character`. Try converting your variable(s) with `as.numeric()`. You may need to repeat that process for other variables (such as `vulnerable`) which you manually added, e.g.:

```
nj <- nj %>% 
  mutate(births = as.numeric(births),
         vulnerable = as.numeric(vulnerable))
```

Then your code should work fine.

Comment: Doesn't a character element that does not consist of numbers always and inevitably evaluate to NA if coerced to numeric? For example, `v <- c(1.2, 3.1, 4.555, "ABC")
> as.numeric(v)
[1] 1.200 3.100 4.555    NA`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann True, but I assumed that `births` is in fact intended to be a (exclusively) numeric vector but was (accidentally) stored as a character instead, as in: `x <- c("1", "2", "3")`. This is a character, but when calling `as.numeric(x)` everything gets converted just fine. If there are indeed non-numeric values in `births`, then it wouldn't make any sense to try and compute the `sum` of it in the first place. Though that's something that only OP can clarify.